# how to install firefox.tar.bz2 on kali linux

Tags: shell-script, software-installation, kali-linux

I have downloaded the firefox.tar.gz2 file and archieved it. How to get it running? I am running Kali Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the archive:

```
tar xvf firefox.tar.gz2
cd firefox
```

then run

```
ln -s /path/to/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
```

Run it:

```
/usr/bin/firefox
```

**Example**:

To install firefox 48 run the following commands :

```
cd /usr/local
```

Downlod the tarball

**64bit**

```
wget https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/48.0/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-48.0.tar.bz2
```

**32 bit**

```
wget https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/48.0/linux-i686/en-US/firefox-48.0.tar.bz2
```

Extract & run it:

```
tar xvf firefox-48.0.tar.bz2
sudo ln -s /usr/local/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
/usr/bin/firefox
```